# Must I provide a command when running a docker container?

Tags: docker, centos

I'd like to install mysql server on a [centos:6.6](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/) container.

However, when I run `docker run --name myDB -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d centos:6.6`, I got `docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.` error.

Checking the document from `docker run --help`, I found that the `COMMAND` seems to be an optional argument when executing `docker run`. This is because `[COMMAND]` is placed inside a pair of square brackets.

> $ docker run --help
>
> Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
>
> Run a command in a new container

I also find out that the [official repository of mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) doesn't specify a command when starting a MySQL container:

> Starting a MySQL instance is simple:
>
> `$ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag`

Why should I provide a command when running a centos:6.6 container, but not so when running a mysql container?

I'm guessing that maybe centos:6.6 is specially-configured so that the user must provide a command when running it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use centos:6.6, you do need to provide a command when you issue "docker run" command.

The reason the officical repository of mysql does not specify a command is because it has CMD command in it's docker file: CMD ["mysqld"]. Check it's docker file [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/5b1a6a2b50efceac44579df0936facfee654a805/5.5/Dockerfile).

The CMD in docker file is the default command when run the container without a command.

You can read [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) to better understand what you can use in a docker file.

In your case, you can

1. Start your centos 6.6 container
2. Take official mysql docker file as reference, issue similar command (change apt-get to yum ( or sudo yum if you don't use the default root user)
3. Once you can successfully start mysql, you can put all your command in your docker file, just to make sure the first line is "From centos:6.6"
4. Build your image
5. Run a container with your image, then you don't need to provide a command in docker run
6. You can share your docker file in docker hub, so that other people can user yours.

good luck.

Comment: Why do I see `CMD ["/bin/bash"]` in the [docker file of centos](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/298ec183aa5886d8184256a1fc94b7618411f426/docker/Dockerfile)?

Comment: It's the default command when you start your container with centos image. you can still provide a command to override it in your "docker run".

Comment: try "docker run  centos:6/6 /bin/echo ABC", here you override "/bin/bash" by "/bin/echo ABC"

Comment: I mean if centOS provides a default command, why must I provide a command for it?

Comment: I think this is the docker file for centos:6:6: https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/8911843d9a6cc71aadd81e491f94618aded94f30/docker/Dockerfile. You can see there is no CMD, so you need to provide one. Sorry, I believe I was looking into centos:6 docker file, which did has a CMD command there.